# Changing background color for drowpdown makes selected items totally white in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have tried to design a dark dropdown menu using Bootstraps `dropdown` classes and additional styling via CSS. The problem is that when the mouse hovers over the dropdown-items they turn totally white (white text on brightbackground). See the result in this image:

[image]

The code for the image above is showed below. I have used inline styles to clarify:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown menu
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: black" >
            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't find how I can change the hover behaviour or style. I would like the text to turn dark for readibility. How can I achieve this? Are there any classes or other tricks in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add CSS to the hover state of the link in the dropdown.

```css
a:hover {
  color: #000!important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown menu
        </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: black">
        <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Edit:** I have used `!important` so that it overrides the inline CSS in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this to your CSS (change blue with the color you want):

```css
.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown menu
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: black" >
            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" style="color:white" href="#">Item 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Don't forget the `!important`, as the attribute is being overwritten by some other rule in your system.

**Update**

I just read that the question was to darken the text. What I did is to change the white background. I'll still let the answer here, because maybe it will be helpful for someone else.

Comment: This was a nice and simple answer. Thanks. The goal was to make the hovered text readable, either by changing the background or the text color. So, this solution is perfectly fine. I liked that you addressed the `.dropdown-item` class instead of the `a` element